# reCAPTCHA Invisible with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, recaptcha

I currently run into the issue that when I use reCAPTCHA invisible (with newly set API keys for it) my validator for `'g-recaptcha-response' => 'required|captcha'` throws an error saying `The g-recaptcha-response field is required`.

I use a common form structure:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ url('/register') }}">
    ...
    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-size="invisible" data-sitekey="sitekey"></div> 
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Register</button>
</form>
```

Will the g-recaptcha-response field not automatically be filled with data?

Comment: Did you include the JS required for reCaptcha? 

`<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>`

Comment: sorry, but yes I did. The captcha gets displayed just fine (in the bottom right corner saying protected by recaptcha)

Comment: Here is the unofficial google Invisible reCAPTCHA PHP library https://github.com/geordyjames/google-Invisible-reCAPTCHA . Read its documentation first. Hope it will be helpful to you although it is for core PHP.